# Camera crash in android native code(libc.so) in Oreo

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, native

I am facing a crash while trying to use camera through SurfaceView. The crash report flies through the logcat and can only be seen by selecting "No filters". I am facing it only in Oreo(8.1).

```
Build fingerprint: 'google/bullhead/bullhead:8.1.0/OPM3.171019.014/4503998:user/release-keys'
Revision: 'rev_1.0'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 26381, tid: 26381, name: application-name  >>> package-name <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'Could not write wake signal to fd 48: Bad file descriptor'
    r0 00000000  r1 0000670d  r2 00000006  r3 00000008
    r4 0000670d  r5 0000670d  r6 ffc192cc  r7 0000010c
    r8 00000000  r9 e50da000  sl 12ec0800  fp 00000000
    ip 12ef0ea8  sp ffc192b8  lr e57018b1  pc e56fb39a  cpsr 200b0030
backtrace:
    #00 pc 0001a39a  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+63)
    #01 pc 0000655d  /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+156)
    #02 pc 0000fe29  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::wake()+108)
    #03 pc 005cfd97  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5cf000) (android.os.Binder.restoreCallingIdentity [DEDUPED]+102)
    #04 pc 000245c9  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)
```

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: @sinek i couldn't find any thing on this. Mysteriously, this crash seems to have disappeared for me. I remember flashing the OS once, though I am not entirely sure if the crashes stopped immediately after that. If that's something you can do, give it a try.

Comment: Thanks! I've asked that because I'm seeing this in my app on Android 7-10 and I can't figure it out since it happens randomly after prolonged use (using Camera2 API).